# How do I alter a response in flask in the after_request function?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and python. I have a bunch of views that return a dictionary in jsonify() format. For each of these views I'd like to add an after_request handler to alter the response so I can add a key to that dictionary. I have:

```
@app.route('/view1/')
def view1():
  ..
  return jsonify({'message':'You got served!'})

@app.after_request
def after(response):
  d = json.loads(response.response)
  d['altered'] = 'this has been altered...GOOD!'
  response.response = jsonify(d)
  return response
```

The error I get is "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". How do I alter the response dictionary and add a key after the request is completed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`response` is a WSGI object, and that means the body of the response must be an iterable. For `jsonify()` responses that's just a list with just one string in it.

However, you should use either the [`response.data` property](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.data) here to retrieve the response body, as that'll flatten the response iterable for you.

As of Flask 1.0, you don't even have to decode the data from JSON, you can use the new [`Response.get_json()` method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=response#flask.Response.get_json) instead.

The following should work:

```
d = response.get_json()
d['altered'] = 'this has been altered...GOOD!'
response.data = json.dumps(d)
```

*Don't* use `jsonify()` again here; that returns a full new response object; all you want is the JSON response body here.

You can instead assign back to `response.data`, which will take care of encoding back to bytes and adjust the `Content-Length` header to reflect the altered response size.

Comment: As written in the below answer, one can use `get_json()` ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response)) as a shortcut to `json.loads(response.get_data())`. Also in Flask 1.1.x I was unable to use the `set_data(some_json_data)` function to change the data of the response object. Instead as shown in the below example, setting `response.data` to the json directly works!

Comment: @cody.codes: `response.get_json()` was added in Flask 1.0, released after this answer was written.  Setting `response.data` calls `response.set_data(...)`, so if one worked and the other doesn’t then you did something else different.

Answer (score 3):

This looks a bit old as the last reply was written four years ago.

There seems to be a way to get the response without parsing the response data string. Use

```
response.get_json()
```

The response returns a dict object, but as Flask returns an error if you are trying to update a key on a non-dict type. Use as follows:

```
data = response.get_json()

if type(data) is dict:

    data['hi'] = 'hi'

    response.data = json.dumps(data)


return response
```

Comment: You should still use `set_data()` no?

Comment: At least in Flask 1.1.x, `response.data` is a descriptor which calls `get_data()` and `set_data()`, which in this case makes the `response.data` property the same as calling the function `response. set_data()` Source: [Flask docs on Response object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response) (I actually couldn't access `response.set_data(some_json_data)` in this version of Flask hence this comment)