# Python nose test failing on JSON response

Tags: python, json, nosetests, flask-restful

This is the method in ReportRunner class in report_runner.py in my Flask-Restful app:

```
class ReportRunner(object):

  def __init__(self):
        pass

  def setup_routes(self, app):
      app.add_url_rule("/run_report", view_func=self.run_report)

  def request_report(self, key):
    # code #

  def key_exists(self, key):
    # code #

  def run_report(self):
    key = request.args.get("key", "")
    if self.key_exists(key):
      self.request_report(report_type, key)
      return jsonify(message = "Success! Your report has been created.")
    else:
      response = jsonify({"message": "Error => report key not found on server."})
      response.status_code = 404
      return response
```

and the nose test calls the URL associated with that route

```
def setUp(self):
    self.setup_flask()
    self.controller = Controller()
    self.report_runner = ReportRunner()
    self.setup_route(self.report_runner)

def test_run_report(self):
    rr = Report(key = "daily_report")
    rr.save()
    self.controller.override(self.report_runner, "request_report")
    self.controller.expectAndReturn(self.report_runner.request_report("daily_report"), True )
    self.controller.replay()
    response = self.client.get("/run_report?key=daily_report")
    assert_equals({"message": "Success! Your report has been created."}, response.json)
    assert_equals(200, response.status_code)
```

and the test was failing with the following message:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'
```

but according to the [docs](https://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it seems that this is how you do it. Do I change the return value from the method, or do I need to structure the test differently?

The test is now passing written like this:

```
json_response = json.loads(response.data)
assert_equals("Success! Your report has been created.", json_response["message"])
```

but I'm not clear on the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: As it is stated, your problem is exactly how the documentation says it should be done.  More context is needed to understand what is going wrong, e.g. the full API method and the full test.

Comment: What is `response.status_code` just before you call `assert_equals()`?

Comment: Also the comments in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398218/getting-json-response-using-requests-object-flask) imply that you might want to use `response.json()` instead of `response.json`. That's not going to fix your issue here, though.

Comment: @SeanAzlin the response code is 200.

Comment: How about `response.data`, `response. mimetype`, and `response.headers`?

Comment: @SeanAzlin the mimetype in the test is `'application/json'` and the headers are `Headers([('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', '57')])`

Comment: A co-worker told me to refactor the test to do this:

Comment: `json_response = json.loads(response.data)
    assert_equals("Success! Your report has been created.", json_response["message"])` and it works but I'm not clear on the difference.

Comment: I think jsonify() needs to get called, but I don't know much about flask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Flask API](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#response-objects) **Response** object doesn't have attribute **json**  (it's **Request** object that has it). So, that's why you get exception. Instead, it has generic method **get_data()** that returns the string representation of response body.

```
json_response = json.loads(response.get_data())
assert_equals("Success! Your report has been created.", json_response.get("message", "<no message>"))
```

So, it's close to what you have except:

- **get_data()** is suggested instead of data as API says:  *This should not be used and will eventually get deprecated.*
- reading value from dictionary with **get()** to not generate exception if key is missing but get correct assert about missing message.

Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274137/how-do-i-alter-a-response-in-flask-in-the-after-request-function) also.